# How to reset user's decision in ACAccountStore?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, social-framework

I am using ACAccountStore to get access to the user's Facebook account, if configured in OS X.  After calling `requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion:`, a dialog asking for permissions to access the Facebook account is shown to the user. The two available options are "Yes" and "No". If the user selects "No" in this dialog, the access is not granted, which makes perfect sense. Unfortunately I have not found a way to ask the same question to the user at a later stage again. Every further call to `requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion:` results in an immediate response of a denied request. There is no dialog popping up anymore.

My question is now whether it is possible to reset the user's initial decision somehow to show the request dialog another time?

Comment: I don't think so, you may choose to open a dialog box to ask user to go to Setting app and grant you the facebook account access

Comment: But even that's not possible. At least, I don't see that option to grant access on a per-app basis?!

Comment: I have to correct myself: In System Preferences under Privacy, the user can change the access status for a particular application.